# How to call a overloaded method by reflection using class name, method name and Object[] arguments?

Tags: java, reflection

I take input the name of class, method name and array of arguments i want to pass in it. I want to call that method of that class and run it for the arguments user gave.
The arguments are given as Object[] args
Class name and method name as String.

This Class has multiple methods of the same name but different arguments. I need to be able to analyse the argument array and work out which variant fits best, according to the rules in the Java Language Specification.

Comment: The reflection api is a little slow, but it's well documented. Try that. Come back with a reasonable attempt. You can start with [The Reflection API trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html).

Comment: do i really need reflection to do it? or i can directly call that method

Comment: Why don't you know the argument types?  What will you do if that class has more than one method with that name?  Are you expecting to be able to analyse the argument array and work out which variant fits best, according to the rules in the Java Language Specification?

Comment: the joinPoint only give me this object[] args of the method i put aspect on. I need to call some other method with the arguments passed in the method on which i have put aspect.

Comment: You really need the reflection api to call a method by reflection; **please** read [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/243725)

Comment: The easiest way is to use an `java.beans.Expression`.

Comment: So, what do you want to do if the class has more than one method with the given name?

Comment: the Object[] args i have.. Based os the types of args it should chose that method

Comment: Again: read the documentation about reflection, then come back with a specific question. What you intend to do is an advanced, complicated topic. And reflection is simply something that turns you crazy as there are zillions of subtle ways to get your code wrong. Don't expect easy answers here.

Comment: OK, sorry, I thought you said you don't know the argument types.  What you're asking for is awfully complicated.  The rules that Java uses to choose between overloaded methods are quite detailed.  I would suggest you read the relevant chapter of the Java Language Specification, and make sure you understand the rules, before you think too hard about how to implement them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to do the lookup and method selection yourself, then an java.beans.Expression can help:

```
String className = ...
String methodName = ...
Object[] arguments = ...

Object result = new Expression(Class.forName(className), methodName, arguments).getValue();
```

This only works for static methods, through.
If you want to call an instance method, you also need an instance, in which case the class name would not be needed.

Comment: i have the class name

Comment: If you want to invoke an instance method, you have to pass the instance as first parameter to the constructor.